# #ckan harvesting connection refused

Tags: ckan

I followed all the steps mentioned in [ckanext-harvest github guide](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest/blob/master/README.rst). I get an error

[image: Error]

and `127.0.0.1:5000\harvest` shows following error:

[image: Error]

Following are the changes in configuration file:

ckan.harvest.mq.type = redis under [app:main]
ckan.plugins = stats text_view image_view recline_view recline_grid_view datastore datapusher resource_proxy recline_preview harvest ckan_harvester

I followed the instructions more than 10 times but connection refused and template not found is the error that comes from `localhost/harvest` and `localhost:5000/harvest` respectively.

How might I resolve this error?

[image: Error]

Comment: Hi Tanya, you have checked that you don't have duplicated the `ckan.plugins` rule in your **development.ini**, right?

Comment: I have only one line of ckan plugin under app:main section  ckan.plugins = stats text_view image_view recline_view harvest ckan_harvester

Comment: for windows 
http://stackoverflow.com/questionhttp://stackoverflow.com/users/7056522/tanya-aroras/41839056/templatenotfound-when-installing-ckan-python-extension

Comment: It solved my problem replace template=template.replace('/', '\\') and template.split('\\')